# Execute command after changing directory

Tags: batch-file, yarnpkg

I am trying to write a bat file open `cmd` change directory then kick off yarn.

This is what i have so far.  It opens `cmd` and changes directory then it opens a **second** `cmd` window and runs the yarn command in the original directory.

```
start cmd /k cd /D C:\Development\project\X.WebApp 
start yarn start --port 4201
```

I however want to `cd` to the directory and execute yarn in the same *cmd* window inside of the `cd`'d directory.

```
start cmd /k cd /D C:\Development\project\X.WebApp yarn start --port 4201
```

**Where yarn**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.js
```

**Currently what i have to do**

- open cmd.
- change directory to C:\Development\project\X.WebApp
- type yarn start --port 4201
- wait for application to start.
- Leave window open

I would like to have this all in a single bat file that i can kick off and have it do all three things for me rather than me having to type this all the time.  I have no preference to it being in a single line command.

Comment: Why not simply using the `/D` option: `start "" /D "C:\Development\project\X.WebApp" cmd /K yarn start --port 4201`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to start yarn in the same window instead of opening a new window.

```
@echo off
cd /D "C:\Development\project\X.WebApp\"
start "" /b yarn start --port
pause
```

Comment: You are my hero.  Swear i tried something like that already Think it was the pause i was missing.

Answer (score 1):

For your stated issue, I would forget about explicitly changing directory, and utilising the options of the `Start` command already in use, specifically it's `/D` option.

```bat
Start /B /D "C:\Development\project\X.WebApp" Cmd /K "yarn start --port 4201"
```

Comment: I am not requesting a single line command.  I just want to be able to run a bat file have it open a cmd window and run the yarn thing so that i dont have to open a cmd change directory and type this command every time manually.    I have no preference to it being in a single line command.

Comment: Your command just flash opens the cmd window and exists it.  It doesnt start the server

Comment: `Cmd /K` opens a `cmd.exe` window and keeps it open, if you were to remove the yarn command, leaving just `Start /D "C:\Development\project\X.WebApp" Cmd /K` you'd clearly see that a new cmd.exe will be opened with `C:\Development\project\X.WebApp` as the current directory. So taking that into account my command does what you've asked , it opens a new cmd.exe window with the directory placed in the `/D` option as the curerent working directory and runs the command you've given it. As you've now changed you question body, I have adjusted my answer to suit those changes, specifically using `/B`.

Answer (score 0):

In windows batch file you can run commands one after another using `&&`:

```
start cmd /k cd /D C:\Development\project\X.WebApp && yarn start --port 4201
```

If the cd command succeeds then then yarn command will be run.

Comment: Sorry not working.  It changes the directory but it doesn't start yarn